# Why do I get "cannot call doValidate of undefined" when saving a model using Mongoose.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Could someone please help try and explain what I'm doing wrong using mongoose.js ORM and give me some guidance in how to fix the problem.

## Problem

When trying to save a model using mongoose.js orm I receive an error:

**Cannot call method 'doValidate' of undefined**

### Schema Definition

I'm trying to save the object with this schema:

```
var myEntity = new Schema({
  objectId            : ObjectId
  ,title             : String
  , decription        : String
  , ownerId           : String
  , start               : {
     something : {
      // ...
     }
   //removed for brevity!
  }
  , end             : {
     something : {
      // ...
     }
   //removed for brevity!
    }
  , useruid           : String
  , _created          : { type : Date, "default": new Date()}
  , _updated          : { type : Date, "default": new Date()}
}
mongoose.model("MyEntity", MyEntity);
```

### Definining the models

I've placed the models in a container so that I can access them by doing:

```
var xyz = new models['whatever']();
```

The container object looks like:

```
var models = {
  MyEntity : mongoose.model("MyEntity"),
};
```

### Creating the model

I create the model, passing in a JSON object with all the right 'mapping' or attributes:

```
var newEntity = new models.MyEntity(someObj);
```

### Saving the model

Then the code below is how I save the model:

```
newEntity.save(function(error) {

                  if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  }

                  writePostEntityResponse(newEntity);
                });
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong and the error message, although clear, isn't helping me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I get that error it's because *I've tried to save a field that doesn't exist*, perhaps because I've altered a form or something.

Mongo creates ObjectIds automatically.  Have you tried removing that field and seeing what happens?

Comment: Thanks John - Your first sentence : '...I've tried to save a field that doesn't exist' made me check the data I was sending through, and I noticed a typo in a field name which, when fixed, sorted everything out!

Comment: Awesome Lewis!  This is my first ever chosen answer.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The order should be important. If you define `models` before you attach the schema to the models then your dealing with the correct objects.

```
var schema = new Schema(...);
mongoose.model('ModelName', mySchema)
var models = {
    "foo": mongoose.model('ModelName')
}
var xyz = new models['foo']();
xyz.save();
```

As to the error message, mongoose has a validation system in build, so whenever you save it, it will validate. By default there are no validation rules so it does nothing. Again it seems like the model object your trying to save is missing something, maybe the schema, maybe the validation code.

Comment: @Lewis it could have been an easy thing to forget!

Comment: It was there, through, my updated post you can see that I'm accessing the models in probably a not so standard way! Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: @Lewis the order is important you should define the model with the schema before you initialize `models`.

Comment: @Raynos - I am though, new Schema > mongoose.models(...) > new model(...) > xyz.save() :  right?

Comment: @Raynos. I believe this is what I'm doing.

I export the models container as a module and call:
var xyz = new models['foo']();
xyz.save();

Any more ideas?